# Are there other methods on clicking an element?

Tags: protractor

I already tried the following codes but the element was not clicked.

```
    global.elmCBSave.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(global.elmCBSave.getWebElement())
        .click(protractor.Button.LEFT).perform();       
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(global.elmCBSave.getWebElement())
        .mouseDown().mouseUp()
        .click(protractor.Button.LEFT).perform();       
    browser.sleep(2000);
```

The property of element was not tagged as a button, it was tagged as a span and looks like a link.

```
    <a class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small" style="min-width: 75px; right: auto; left: 328px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" role="button" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" id="button-1011" tabindex="-1" data-componentid="button-1011"> 
        <span id="button-1011-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-small ">
            <span id="button-1011-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center ">
                <span id="button-1011-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-small  " style=""></span>
                <span id="button-1011-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small">Save</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
```

The global.elmCBSave is:

```
global.elmCBSave = element(by.cssContainingText('.x-btn-inner.x-btn-inner-default-small', 'Save'));
```

Note: cssContainingText was used because the Cancel button have same css:

```
<span id="button-1013-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small">Cancel</span>
```

I also tried sending TAB key and then ENTER key, but nothing happens, it just focuses on the button.

Answer (score 0):

> Try any one of the following . Hope it helps you.

As you can see Save and Cancel is having same values so it is not possible to separate them using any of the selector. 
You can try Indexing them as follows:

```
browser.findElement(by.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'button')][2]")).click();
browser.findElement(by.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'button')][3]")).click();
```

> OR go through text.

```
browser.findElement(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Save')]").click();
browser.findElement(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]").click();
```

This remains for using Dyanmic selection.

```
browser.findElement(by.cssSelector("*[id^='button'][id$='InnerEl']")).click();
```

Learn more at [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)

Comment: #1 and #3 lines can't be used because the integer there is dynamic.    #2 I added a close parenthesis before ".click()", but it still did not click the element.

Comment: `class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small" data-ref="btnInnerEl"` what about this? These are also dynamic ?

Comment: This is my current element  

global.elmCBSave = element(by.cssContainingText('.x-btn-inner.x-btn-inner-default-small', 'Save'));

Comment: What is dynamic in this `button-1011-btnInnerEl`?? 1011 is dynamic? M i right?

Comment: yup the 1011, the integer.

Comment: Not to worry. See my edited answer. It will pick the id dynamically with the help of start i.e. `button` and end i.e. `InnerEl`

Comment: I also updated the question, there is also a cancel button with same css, they only differ on the dynamic integer value.

Comment: These are the only options. Edited my final answer. Thank You.

Comment: the index starts with 2 and not 0?

Comment: I mean, this lines
browser.findElement(by.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'button')][2]")).click();
browser.findElement(by.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'button')][3]")).click();

Comment: Whatever indexing you get for save and cancel, just use that. The html code which you provided is limited where it was pointing to 2 and 3.

Comment: still no luck. :( when running it automatically regardless of the method used, you can see that the button was clicked, but still nothing happens.

Comment: Please share me the link where you clicking. It is really difficult to help.

Comment: it is behind a proxy and can't be shared :(

Comment: If you really want me to help. Please add the whole html dom in your question for that page. attach screenshot of save and cancel inspecting them with f12.

Comment: I was able to find out that they used the [add-in](http://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/kitchensink/#examples/multiassignment).   
But when I am running protractor using IE, it only opens the browser and then an error appear stating "Unable to get browser". :(